# How to mock a private method called inside another private method

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I was trying to mock a private method's output which is being called inside another private method, I have no choice but to test the later private method, so I have added sample test code which I can represent here,

**This Sample Class**

```
package com.testableClass;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class TestableClass {
    
     private int initialMockMethod(Object obj)
     {
         
         System.out.println(" ++++ Came Here ++++ ");
         
         String str = getRestString("");
         
         System.out.println("str ="+str);
         return str.length();
     }

     private String getRestString(String abc)
     {
         String output="";
         try {

                URL url = new URL("https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users");//your url i.e fetch data from .
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : "
                            + conn.getResponseCode());
                }
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
                
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(output);
                }
                conn.disconnect();
                
                return output;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in NetClientGet:- " + e);
            }
        return abc;
     }
     
}
```

**Now This PowerMock Class**

```
package com.testableClass;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;

import junit.framework.Assert;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames = "com.testableClass.TestableClass")
public class PowerMockTest {
    

    
    @Test
    public void testPrivateMethod() throws Exception
    {
        String message = "Hello PowerMockito";
        String expectation = "Expectation";
 
        TestableClass mock = PowerMockito.spy(new TestableClass());
//      PowerMockito.doReturn(expectation).when(mock, "getRestString", message);
        PowerMockito.when(mock, "getRestString", message).thenReturn(expectation);
        int count = Whitebox.invokeMethod(mock, "initialMockMethod", new Object());
       System.out.println(" +++ Count : "+count+" ++++ ");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

my issue is when I am running my test case then

```
  PowerMockito.when(mock, "getRestString", message).thenReturn(expectation);
```

executes original method and returns original output while my requirement is that,
when my test case is actually calling private method **initialMockMethod** it should not call **getRestString** instead of that it should return my mocked expected output which is **"Expectation"**

Comment: Don't. If you need to know this much detail about them, they *shouldn't be private*.

Comment: that code is not suitable for unit testing. unit testing means that you need to start thinking about writing testable code first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using reflection and PowerMock, I'd say that do not try to mock a private method. It is a hidden detail of the class.

What I suggest is that, if your method makes an HTTP request, then let it do that. But you can use a mock server to mock the response. But to do that, you need to make your endpoint external, so that it can be injected.

I changed your class a little bit; still the same purpose tho.

```java
public class TestableClass {
    private final String resourceUrl;

    public TestableClass(String resourceUrl) {
        this.resourceUrl = resourceUrl;
    }

    public int publicMethod() {
        return initialMockMethod(null);
    }

    private int initialMockMethod(Object obj) {
        var str = getRestString("");
        return str.length();
    }

    private String getRestString(String abc) {
        try {
            var url = new URL(resourceUrl);
            var conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            var in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            var br = new BufferedReader(in);

            var result = br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            conn.disconnect();

            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in NetClientGet:- " + e);
        }
        return abc;
    }

}
```

and here's the test

```java
public class TestingTestableClass {

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void test() {
        final var server = new MockWebServer();
        server.start(9999);

        var instance = new TestableClass("http://127.0.0.1:9999");

        server.enqueue(
                new MockResponse()
                    .setResponseCode(200)
                    .setBody("this is the response")
        );

        final int result = instance.publicMethod();

        Assertions.assertEquals(
                "this is the response".length(),
                result
        );

        final var record = server.takeRequest();
        final var method = record.getMethod();
        Assertions.assertEquals("GET", method);

        server.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Check out MockWebServer [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver)

Comment: I got your point here but my challange is tthe change u did I can not do as my structure is defined already where I have been asked to test a private method

Comment: now in that private method another private method is being called which internally calls multiple other private method and data base calls to produce result

Comment: Now my this code is just a representation that getString method is a just representation of a complex private method which is being called by another private method and this caller method I have to tes using whitebox

Comment: Here whatever changes u did is ok for this scenario but its merely representation of some other properitery code which I can not post here

Comment: So my doubt is still there that can I mock internal private tire two methods while testing private tier 1 method of same class

Comment: here tier 1 is initialMockMethod while tier 2 or level 2 method I am trying to say to getString which is called internally and contains complex logics using database and rest calles

Comment: The idea was if I can do a mock of a private complex method of the same class of which the method I am testing is calling it then I can bypass all those injection Datasource Connection creation  and rest calls

Comment: otherwise, I have to mock each and every external dependency one by one and their results to test the class and all these because of one method of same class I can not mock

Comment: @AtulSinghRathore you can move some of those private methods to another class since I believe this class is doing too much. You can then add that class as a dependency and you can mock that.